# Is there any way to make right to left value assigning in linq or in any other way

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

The title is pretty unclear. But I couldn't find the proper words. Generally Linq works in the below syntax

```
MyList.Where().Select(x => {MyFunction(x);})
```

It is good in ordinary conditions but in some situation like in my case. I am creating a tree structure using dictionary. In this if I want to add a set

```
Set.Foreach(x => {(MyDict[logEvent.level][logEvent.event][logEvent.subevent][logEvent.filePath]).Add(x);});
```

But it would be nice if I can do like below

```
(MyDict[logEvent.level][logEvent.event][logEvent.subevent][logEvent.filePath]).Add(MySet.Foreach(x => {return x;}));
```

Is there any way possible to dothis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, if object stored in `Dict` has `AddRange` method which accepts `IEnumerable<T>`. But you should ski[ `ForEach` and just pass `MySet`:

```
MyDict[logEvent.level][logEvent.event][logEvent.subevent][logEvent.filePath]).AddRange(MySet);
```

Comment: @Marin No luck. HashSet doesn't provide AddRange function. And I don't like to make extension just for a single line.

Comment: @prabhakaran For `HashSet<T>` use [`UnionWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097(v=vs.110).aspx).